# Open and close 2 distinct Scanners in java project

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is super simplified code of what I was doing, but the results are the same. I can comment out in.close() in class 1 and it will fix the error. But then I'm left with an open Scanner for the rest of the project. And changing the variable names are not a fix.

class1:

```
package scannerDebug;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {
    private String name_;

public Class1(String name)  {
    name_ = name;   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Your name: ");
    Class1 ex1 = new Class1(in.next());
    System.out.println("eex1" + ex1.name_);
    in.close(); 
    }
}
```

class2

```
package scannerDebug;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class2 {
private String name_;

public Class2(String name)  {
    name_ = name;   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Your name: ");
    Class2 ex2 = new Class2(in.next());
    System.out.println("ex2" + ex2.name_);
    in.close();
    }
}
```

Driver class
    package scannerDebug;

```
public class driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class1.main(args);
    Class2.main(args);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing a `Scanner` also closes the underlying stream.  To solve this, simply use a single `Scanner` in your `driver` class and use it in both `Class1` and `Class2`:

```
public class driver {
    private static final SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1.main(args);
        Class2.main(args);
    }

    public static Scanner getScanner() {
        return SCANNER;
    }
}
```

---

```
public Class2(String name) {
    name_ = name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Your name: ");
    Class2 ex2 = new Class2(driver.getScanner().next());
    System.out.println("ex2" + ex2.name_);
}
```

I recommend you follow proper conventions and change your variable/class names.

You could also pass the `Scanner` to each class via their respective constructors, but I thought you might want to run `Class1` or `Class2` without running `driver` first.

Comment: Usually my variable names are actually suited to the project, this was just a quick example.
I would never actually use 'Class1' or "ex1' in something real. 
And is there a way to reopen the stream or is it one of those things where once it's closed, its closed?

Comment: @KileyCampbell Gotcha, and it's the latter, unfortunately.